# DLL needs symbols (a class) from the app it will link to

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, dllimport

I cannot get a DLL to link, that needs a class exported from the app this DLL will be used with.  Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7.

I had a small sample DLL compiling (the default MSFT DLL project actually), and the app can use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` on it correctly.  I'm experienced with dllimport/dllexport. Using `dumpbin /exports` was critical to discover the mangled names to use with `GetProcAddress()` (MSFT's default empty DLL includes a sample function without `extern "C"`) but this is a solved problem.

The next step was to have the app export a class that the DLL will need to subclass.  I do the dllimport/dllexport `#define`'s in the reverse sense from usual: a special symbol when the app is compiled tags the class with dllexport and non-app code (such as the DLL) using that header, without the special symbol, gets a dllimport spec.  `dumpbin /exports` on the .exe file shows exactly this class's (mangled) symbols being exported, and no others, as expected.

The next step was to have the DLL include the header and create an object of the exported object's type (as a baby-step towards actually subclassing it).  Compiles fine, but linker shows error:

```
DynTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Test::Test(class Toast*,double)" (??0Test@@QAE@PAVToast@@N@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDynTest::CDynTest(void)" (??0CDynTest@@QAE@XZ)
```

OK, that didn't surprise me, as I know on WIN32 I need to supply DLL's at link time to make a DLL, unlike my usual Unix.  Since Windows seems to treat DLLs and executables a bit similarly, I tried adding the .exe at Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.  That gets an error that looks like `LINK.EXE` didn't auto-detect that it was being given an .exe:

```
T:\mypath\MyBinary.exe : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x348
```

I then tried adding instead the object file that defines this class... That seems to be understood by the linker, and is probably successfully satisfying the DLL's need to link, but now shows a myriad of other symbols this file depends upon.

So I've considered refactoring the app such that most of it is in a DLL or LIB, just so I can supply that as an "Additional Dependencies" to the DLL I'm actually worried about.  But this seems to be draconian.  Is that my only option?

Comment: Do you expect to be able to change the EXE and have the DLL use the new version of the superclass? I don't think that's possible. It also doesn't seem like the right place for the superclass ... the application uses the DLL, not really the other way around. Put the superclass in the DLL.

Comment: I hope to rebuild the app and use old DLLs, but NOT to change the class the DLL inherits from.  The API will be steady in that respect.  The symbols won't change (or reorder, or have new symbols added before them, if these are things MSFT can't cope with).  I agree the requirements might seem perplexing, but those are the requirements for this project.  Think in terms of the DLL allowing user customization of an app base class.  Now: I can certainly implement different TECHNICAL implementations the LOGICAL MODEL.  But the model isn't changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `dumpbin /exports` gives you a list of mangled names of exe exports. You need to create a module definition file (.def) containing these names:

```
EXPORTS
   @d3d_some_fancy_mangedled_method_1
   @d3d_some_fancy_mangedled_method_2
   ...
```

Notice that it is basically dumpbin output with first columns removed.
Then you use `lib` tool to generate export library from module definition file:

```
LIB /DEF:prog.def /NAME:prog.exe /MACHINE:x86
```

Finally you link generated export library `prog.lib` into your application. `/MACHINE` option should match to your executable. Notice that you don't need to link or anyhow use program executable to link it, only export library is used.

Comment: Thx VTT, trying...   IT WORKS!  But Q1: "first columns removed"--the name column of dumpbin's output is of the format "string = otherstring".  LIB seems happy with just "otherstring", and with "string = otherstring".  But the link stage of the DLL build only works with "string = otherstring" so I assume that's correct--but can you confirm?  Q2: by "link generated export library prog.lib into your application" do you mean DLL, right?  Not application?

Comment: Q1:  for me dumpbin output contains 4 colums: `ordinal`, `hint`, `RVA`, `name`. Only `name` is relevant. Q2: it does not matter, you can link into dll and into exe.