# How do i load symbols & variables into a DLL File from the main process thats using the same header files? (-rdynamic on linux basically)

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-linking

First of all, I'm not very experienced with DLL Files so sorry if this seems like such a beginner question.

On linux, you can compile a shared library with -rdynamic flag that makes the symbols from the main process to load into the loaded shared library, i want to do the same with the DLL File but i am not sure how, i've already created an ".a" file with the following commands: 
`ar libvault.a bin_win/*.o` 
and 
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool --export-all-symbols main.exe -l libvault.a -D main.exe` 
but none of these work! 
I really don't know what to do

The code for loading the DLL file:

```cpp
// shared object structure:
struct SharedObject {
  std::string name;
  std::string typeName;
  HINSTANCE handle;
  Script *(*create)();
};

// script class
class Script {
public:
  std::string objId;
  std::string name;

  virtual void Start(){};
  virtual void Update(){};
};

sharedObj.handle = LoadLibrary(file.c_str());
sharedObj.create = (Script * (*)()) GetProcAddress(sharedObj.handle, "create_object");
sharedObj.name = dirEntry.path().filename().string();
```

DLL File code:

```cpp
// NewScript.hpp
#pragma once 
 #include <api.hpp> 
 
 using namespace HyperAPI; 
 using namespace HyperAPI::Experimental; 
 
 #ifdef _WIN32 
 #ifdef BUILD_DLL 
 #define VAULT_API __declspec(dllexport) 
 #else 
 #define VAULT_API __declspec(dllimport) 
 #endif 
 #else 
 #define VAULT_API 
 #endif 
 
 extern "C" { 
 class NewScript : CppScripting::Script { 
 public: 
     NewScript() = default; 
     ~NewScript() = default; 
 
     void Start() override; 
     void Update() override; 
 }; 
 
 VAULT_API NewScript *create_object(); 
 }
```

```cpp
// NewScript.cpp
#include "NewScript.hpp" 
NewScript *create_object() { 
    return new NewScript; 
} 
 
void NewScript::Start() {
    Log log("start", LOG_INFO);
    // this Log class escencially adds it into a vector variable that gets iterated in ImGui to be displayed
} 
void NewScript::Update() {
    Log log("update", LOG_WARNING);
}
```

```cpp
// Somewhere in programming
Script *script = sharedObj.create();
script->Start(); // when this gets called, the logs variable doesn't get updated in the main process while it does on linux with ".so" files
```

when compiling the DLL, i link the libvault.a file and add -DBUILD_DLL 

I've read all questions i could from stackoverflow that was similar to this and searched it on other sites too but nothing worked

Comment: You want to build an export library for your .exe and link your dll against it as explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553033/dll-needs-symbols-a-class-from-the-app-it-will-link-to)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI just read it and it seems like its using MSVC to compile the code, im using mingw on linux to compile to windows, not msvc so it wont really help with my case, thanks though

Comment: It doesn't matter what compiler you use, they all do the same thing. Mingw has all the tools too [see](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Answer%20generation%20of%20DLL%20import%20library/).

Comment: i completely forgot dlltool exists my bad

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it after searching through compile flags and this is the way I found it:
I add `__declspec(dllexport)` on all stuff I want to export from the main process to the DLL file so like:

```cpp
// header file
#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef BUILD_DLL
        #define DLL_API
    #else
        #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
#else
    #define DLL_API
#endif

DLL_API extern std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
```

```cpp
// cpp file
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects = {};
int main() {
 // do stuf
}
```

Compile command:
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -static -g -Og -std=c++20 -Wa,-mbig-obj bin_win/*.o -o main.exe -Wl,--export-all-symbols,--out-implib,libhost.a $(win_flags)`

This will generate an archive file which you link against the DLL File so it'll have references, other than that all the variables and functions will load from the main process!